# Duplication of same content with insertHtml Medium.js

Tags: vue.js, medium.js

When we bind `v-model` with `contenteditable` then cursor move to start if we update content. So then i decided to use [Medium.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js) which solve my cursor issue with `vuejs`. But here I have some other issue. I try to solve but can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

**Description**
When `keypress` `space` i get content and save it to some variable. Then i replaced some content in saved string and `set` to `medium` again.

**Expected**
Content should replace and overwrite to old content.

**Issue**
After `space` `keypress` same content is copied and paste along with old content. Even if i press `space` key multiple time.

**Live Example**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arifhussain/xpvt214o/984547/)

Comment: That is what you are telling it to do. You pull the text, make a substitution, and then insert the modified string. Maybe you want to replace the text?
The cursor position issue is not specific to Vue, though.